# Running a Virtual Machine and Hypervisor on the same machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I've got a desktop and a laptop computer. Both run Intel hardware. I mainly do word processing, programming, watching videos and surfing the Internet (I don't play computer games). I would like to create a portable Ubuntu installation that I can run both on the desktop and the laptop by installing a hypervisor with little overhead on the desktop and laptop and then have a virtual machine (Linux) on a USB flash drive. Which hypervisor is best suited for this? I've already tried a bootable USB flash drive but this sometimes freezes.

Comment: A virtual machine is a hypervisor.....  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Ramhound mind explaining how a VM is a hypervisor? A hypervisor is a piece of software that virtualizes machines, not the VM itself

Comment: @TD.512 - Your comment does not make sense.  Hyper-V, VirtualBox, VMWare are all Hypervisors.

Comment: @Ramhound you might want to refer to : "A virtual machine is a hypervisor..... Your question is not clear."

Comment: @TD.512 - What are you talking about?

Comment: @Ramhound you said "A virtual machine is a hypervisor..... Your question is not clear." I'm pointing out that no, a VM is *not* a hypervisor

Comment: [really?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) I would disagree.

Comment: @Ramhound. I might be using the wrong terminology here, what I mean is that the hypervisor would act as the host and the virtual machine would be the guest. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @user148095 - So you want to run a virtual machine instead a virtual machine.  [I will again reiterate that a hypervisor is a virtual machine.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor).  What you describe is possible, provided your hardware can support running a Type-1 Hypervisor, only way you will be able to do it.  What isn't clear is WHY you want to do that.  You should simply install Hyper-V ( Windows 8+ ), Virtual Box, or VMWare and just place the .vhdd file on the flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend VirtualBox, as it is cross platform, free (unlike VMware), and can save disk images in lots of different formats. I would caution against saving on a flash drive though, as the extended read/write operation can not only degrade the flash drive, but also cause it to have a shortened lifespan.

**UPDATE**: You would need to boot into an OS such as Windows or Linux with VirtualBox. This would end up running like two OSes. If you want as little overhead as possible, then you need to use a type 1 hypervisor such as VMware ESXi or Citrix XenServer, however that would mean that the PC that has the hypervisor installed would not be able to be used for anything else.

Comment: To use VirtualBox I would need to install an OS then install VirtualBox and then run the virtual machine inside VirtualBox. Would this almost end up like running two OSs in terms of resources. Or is it possible to boot directly into VirtualBox like a hypervisor type 1 (bare metal) and then launch the virtual machine? I like to have as little overhead as possible.

Comment: You can boot directly to type 1 hypervisors, VirtualBox is a type 2, hypervisor